# Aero Snap with Borderless Window in Qt

Tags: qt, borderless, aero-snap

I'm trying to create a Metro-style interface in Qt, which means not using the Windows 7 Aero border. I've already set the window to be borderless and added code to make it draggable and buttons to make it minimize, maximize, and close. However, Aero Snap does not work.

I know it is possible because Visual Studio 2012, MS Word 2013, and Steam all have borderless windows with Aero Snap.

How can I implement Aero Snap into a borderless Qt application? Thanks.

Comment: Did you finally be able to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765561/borderless-window-using-areo-snap-shadow-minimize-animation-and-shake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for this kind of Qt window and I have finally found a solution.

This GitHub example does the job like a charm (thanks to deimos1877)!
https://github.com/deimos1877/BorderlessWindow

Be sure to use visual studio compiler to get the needed DLL and it should work.
This example include aerosnap support, borderless window, minimize effect, aero shadows.

Comment: Except the implementation is ugly as hell.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Have you found a better one?

Comment: @Zmey: no, I ditched that idea, non-native windows are a mess.

Comment: To save others time trying: downsides of this approach is that this leaves part of native window shown below the Qt one on the borders. When native window is resized it can go completely under Qt window and no longer stretched back.

Comment: I totally agree with you... Also I haven't found better solution yet...