# Triggering the windows Minimize and Restore animations in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a borderless from in a WinForm project.  (Set with `BorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None`)

To minimize this form I have been calling `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized` however this does not trigger the minimization animation that other windows have.

How can I programatically trigger that minimize animation.  My project is targetting `.NET 4.0`

Comment: In this post maybe you will find the answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641829/formborderstyle-none-removes-the-native-open-effect-of-windows-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473489/use-windows-animations-on-borderless-form/31489766#31489766

Comment: Not a duplicate, that answer only handles minimzing.  No mention of how to do the restore animation.  Also that minimize animation does not appear to work in .NET 4.0