# c# minimize animation lost after setting the FormBorderStyle to none

Tags: c#

I'm making a custom design for my form. I've added a button, which minimizes the form. But, there is a little problem. After I clicked the button, it successfully minimizes, but the animation is lost. Is there any solution to get back the minimize animation?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

Comment: This is because of setting FormBorderStyle to None. You can find some details in these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641829/formborderstyle-none-removes-the-native-open-effect-of-windows-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765561/borderless-window-using-areo-snap-shadow-minimize-animation-and-shake