# Maximize animation on borderless form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

this might sound like a beginner question but I'll ask it anyways

Is there any way to get the normal window maximize animation using WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized?

I tried: Googling and just setting WindowState to FormWindowState.Maximized

Thank you, ItsRedly

Comment: Exactly what does _to get the normal window maximize animation_ mean?

Comment: This is close: [FormBorderStyle.None removes the native open effect of windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707049/7444103) (looking at the code, not tested) -- Replace the `IsCompositionEnabled()` method with `bool IsCompositionEnabled() => !DesignMode && DwmIsCompositionEnabled();` -- Also check [Borderless Window Using Areo Snap, Shadow, Minimize Animation, and Shake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16765561/7444103) (slightly different language)