# Aero snap with borderless window in PyQt5 | PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, win32gui

[Borderless Window Using Areo Snap, Shadow, Minimize Animation, and Shake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765561/borderless-window-using-areo-snap-shadow-minimize-animation-and-shake)

As the title suggests, I want to create a borderless window with aero snap support. I found this example in C++ and I want to adapt this example to pyside or pyqt. Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: To get started, you need the Python bindings for Win32 library, basically equivalent of `#include <windows.h>` for Python. I've never used them, but I'd be very very surprised if they don't exist.