# How to resize and areo snap frameless windows qt6

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt6

Im designed a form in qt designers
I also make my program frameless with using `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`
currently I coded drag windows manually in my program in this way

```cpp
bool Qt6Gui::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick:
    {
        auto* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if (obj == ui.titleRightInfo && mouseEvent->buttons() & Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton)
            QTimer::singleShot(250, this, &Qt6Gui::maximize_restore);
    }
    break;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
    {
        if (obj == ui.titleRightInfo)
        {
            auto* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);

            if (mouseEvent->buttons() & Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton)
            {
                mouse_pos = ui.titleRightInfo->mapToGlobal(mouseEvent->pos());

                onMove = true;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
    case QEvent::MouseMove:
    {
        if (obj == ui.titleRightInfo && onMove)
        {
            auto* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);

            if (mouseEvent->buttons() & Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton)
            {
                auto glb_mousepos = ui.titleRightInfo->mapToGlobal(mouseEvent->pos());
                auto delta = glb_mousepos - mouse_pos;

                if (delta.x() || delta.y())
                {
                    auto newpos = this->pos() + delta;
                    mouse_pos = glb_mousepos;
                    if (GLOBAL_STATE == 1)
                        maximize_restore();
                    this->move(newpos);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
    {
        if (obj == ui.titleRightInfo && onMove)
        {
            auto pos = this->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0));
            if (pos.y() < 0)
            {
                auto old_pos = this->pos();
                this->move(old_pos.x(), old_pos.y() - pos.y() + 1);
            }

            onMove = false;
        }
    }
    break;
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

its working without any problem but its missing areo
and also Im resize my program using QSizeGrip

```cpp
QSizeGrip* sizegrip = new QSizeGrip(ui.frame_size_grip);
sizegrip->setStyleSheet("width: 20px; height: 20px; margin 0px; padding: 0px;");
```

its working too but its usable only for one side of my program
my problem is I want to be able to use areo snap for resize my program (and also be able to resize it from all the edges), I found some solution (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765561/borderless-window-using-areo-snap-shadow-minimize-animation-and-shake) and [this](https://github.com/dfct/TrueFramelessWindow)) but none of them worked as I excepted (maybe because I'm using designer ui file)
I want to know its possible to snap windows against other window and resize it when dragged to the edge of the screen like when we use normal window frame? and also resize it from all the edges freely?
thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some more searching I finally found [this on github](https://github.com/Bringer-of-Light/Qt-Nice-Frameless-Window) its exactly what I wanted.