# Frameless Qt + WinAPI maximized window size is bigger than the availableGeometry()

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I'm struggling to solve the following problem. My window top left corner has negative coordinates when maximized (both x and y are -9), and it's size is actually bigger than the available area.
I'm using WinAPI to get some platform specific features like Aero snap, so it becomes complicated to understand why exactly this problem happens.
My window has the following styles and attributes set:

```
setFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)winId(), GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
```

`WS_CAPTION` is same as `WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME`, so if I remove `WS_DLGFRAME`, maximized size is ok, and I see that the native maximizing animation disappears — but I get the flickering white border when resize because of `WS_SIZEBOX`  (same as `WS_THICKFRAME`). Without `WS_SIZEBOX`  I loose aero snap.
I thought maybe I can do something with maximixed size in `nativeEvent`, so I tried the following:

```
bool FramelessWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, qintptr* result)
{
    if (auto* msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message); msg->message == WM_NCCALCSIZE)
    {
        NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS& params = *reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(msg->lParam);
        if (params.rgrc[0].top != 0)
        {
            --params.rgrc[0].top;
        }
        *result = WVR_REDRAW;
        return true; //this removes the native border and title
    }
    else if (msg->message == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
    {
        if (IsMaximized((HWND)winId()))
        {
            MINMAXINFO* mmi = (MINMAXINFO*)msg->lParam;
            auto g = screen()->availableGeometry();
            mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.x = g.width() * devicePixelRatio();
            mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.y = g.height() * devicePixelRatio();
            *result = 0;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QQuickWindow::nativeEvent(eventType, message, result);
}
```

For some reason, `MINMAXINFO` overloading does nothing until I set `mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.x = g.width() * devicePixelRatio() - 1;`. In this case, the size is almost nice, except that there is a 1 px empty gap between the right border of the screen and the window. So there is no way I can obtain the correct size with changing `MINMAXINFO`, because the real correct size should be actually same as in the above code. The initial ptMaxTrackSize is pretty strange: 3462, 1462 in `mmi` vs 3440, 1390 in `availableGeometry`).

I can do something like that, but I'd like to keep QWindow::Maximized state, which is reset when I call `setGeometry`.

```
bool FramelessWindow::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange && QWindow::visibility() == QWindow::Maximized)
    {
        setGeometry(screen()->availableGeometry()); //the window is no longer maximized
        return true;
    }

    return QQuickWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Since I'm not able to use `QWindow::Maximized` in `setGeometry` approach, this approach equals to implementing my own maximize, normalize and so on, what is undesirable and also won't affect on maximizing with aero.

I also tried to add margins in maximized state, but creating a layout causes ugly flickering when resize, since the instance of my window is created in QML. And I'm unable to use `setLayout` and try to add margins in C++ code, because my class inherited `QQuickWindow`.

Am I missing something?

**UPD:**
Now I have found out that this problem is mainly related to WinAPI + framelessness, not to Qt, so not only Qt users have "window extends beyond the screen when maximized".
It helps a bit, at least I am now able to test the already existing WinAPI solutions, but the problem is they don't work as expected.

I've tried modifying `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` while processing the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message:

Here is what I got in `rgrc[0]`:

[image]

What I've tried according to [melak47's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17713810):

```
void adjustMaximized(HWND hwnd, RECT& rect)
{
    auto monitor = ::MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);
    if (!monitor)
    {
        return;
    }
    MONITORINFO monitor_info{};
    monitor_info.cbSize = sizeof(monitor_info);
    if (!::GetMonitorInfoW(monitor, &monitor_info))
    {
        return;
    }
    rect = monitor_info.rcWork;
}

bool FramelessWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, qintptr* result)
{
    if (auto* msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message); msg->message == WM_NCCALCSIZE)
    {
        NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS& params = *reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(msg->lParam);
        if (params.rgrc[0].top != 0)
        {
            --params.rgrc[0].top;
        }
        if (IsMaximized(hwnd_))
        {
            adjustMaximized(hwnd_, params.rgrc[0]);
        }
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

My top right corner becomes even worse:
[image]